# popup in JSF to set it value in parent Window

Tags: jsf-2

I have written a button onClick to open popup window. The window has a table with a commandLink in each row. How to populate the parent page textbox on click of commandLink in child page?

Answer (score 1):

You can give the commandLink an ajax tag, with whom you render your parent textbox.
Use something like this:

```
<h:inputText id="parentTextboxId" value="#{bean.text}" />

<rich:popupPanel domElementAttachment="form" show="#{bean.showPopup}" modal="true">

    <h:commandLink value="My Link">
        <f:ajax render=":mainForm:parentTextboxId" listener="#{bean.changeText}" />
    </h:commandLink>

</rich:popupPanel>
```

In the bean method `bean#changeText` the value of the textbox will be changed, but you can also do it elsewhere, like in the action method of your `commandLink`

Comment: my parent form id amnnd name is regionMaster and my txtbox is txtRegionID on using this :regionMaster:txtRegionID iam getting error unknown id  cannot locate it in the context of the component regionID

Comment: Did you attach the `rich:popupPanel` to the form by using the tag `domElementAttachment="form"`?